# Is there a bitset class that's sized at instantiation time, but avoids boost::dynamic_bitset<>'s extra allocation call?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, bitset, allocator

Is there a convenient analog of `std::bitset<>` that's dynamically sizable at instantiation time, but avoids the extra allocation required by `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`

You can create dynamically sized bit sets easily in C by doing something like :

```
typedef struct { node_t node; block_t bits[0]; } node_bitset_t;
p = (node_bitset_t *)malloc( (sizeof(node_t) + sizeof(block_t)*blocks) * array_size);
```

You could do this using `std::vector<std::bitset<bits>>` only if you know `bits` at compile time.  If you use `std::vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<>>`, then you'll see an extra allocator call.  Is there a compromise that achieves the above C code's balance?

You might for-example have some custom allocator for the std::vector<...> that leaves some extra space after each `boost::dynamic_bitset<>` and allocates `m_block` there, although that'll probably still cost you the pointer for `m_block`.

Comment: What extra allocation are you talking about?

Comment: There's no *extra* allocation — vs. the C version's malloc — unless you instantiate the `dynamic_bitset` itself on the heap, which you needn't do most of the time. How does the C version avoid extra allocations for an array of `node_bitset_t *`?

Comment: In the C version, all the `node_bitset_t *` require zero size because they're simply the continuation of the struct that has size exactly `sizeof(node_t)`.  We allocate space for the array `bits` using the `malloc` and access it as `bits[i]` or whatever.  There is only one `malloc` in the C version, ditto the compile time sized `std::bitset` version I'd assume, but the `boost::dynamic_bitset` version requires `array_size+1` `new` calls.  I think the stack isn't large enough for the data sets in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be possible to create such a class using placement new, but I'm not aware of a preexisting class which does this. The class wouldn't be instantiated directly but would be built via a factory; the factory method would use `new` to allocate the number of bytes necessary, then use placement new to initialize the object at the front of the buffer. The end of the buffer past the size of the class would be the bit storage.

In practice there's no need to do this, because it doesn't save anything vs. `dynamic_bitset`. With this method you have two parts, a pointer to the bits object and the object itself. With dynamic_bitset you have the dynamic_bitset object which contains the pointer to the bits. Same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I create a ticket in boost for it as feature request: Ticket #13016 (https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/13016)